# Ansible: How do I execute tasks in ansible playbook in parallel with some time gap

Tags: parallel-processing, ansible, execution

Let me try and explain my need:

As part of the regular deployment of our application, we have a SQL script(which would alter tables, add tables or update, etc) which needs to be run on 3 schemas in a region and 5 schemas in another for example. The application is in AWS and the database is Arora db(RDS)- MySQL. This schema can take anywhere between 30 minutes to 3 hours.

**This SQL script needs to be run in parallel and with a delay of 2 minutes between each schema run.**

This is what I have achieved till now:

1. A file having DB details- dbdata.yml

```
---

conn_details:
    - { host: localhost, user: root, password: "Password1!" }
    - { host: localhost, user: root, password: "Password1!" }
```

2. The playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    script_file: "{{ path }}"
  vars_files:
    - dbdata.yml
  tasks:
  - name: shell command to execute script in parallel
    shell: |
      sleep 30s
      "mysql -h {{ item.host }} -u {{ item.user }} -p{{ item.password }} < {{ script_file }} >> /usr/local/testscript.log"
    with_items: "{{ conn_details }}"
    register: sql_query_output
    async: 600
    poll: 0

  - name: Wait for sql execution to finish
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: _jobs
    until: _jobs.finished
    delay: 20  # Check every 20 seconds. Adjust as you like.
    retries: 10
    with_items: "{{ sql_query_output.results }}"
```

1st part- executes the script in parallel and this also includes a time gap of 30 seconds before each execution.

2nd part- picks the **ansible job id** from the registered output and checks if the job is completed or not.

Please note: before including the 30 seconds sleep, this playbook was working fine.

We have following erroneous output upon execution:

```
ansible-playbook parallel_local.yml --extra-vars "path=RDS_script.sql"
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [sample command- ansible-playbook my_sqldeploy.yml --extra-vars "path=/home/NICEONDEMAND/bsahu/RDS_create_user1.sql"] ****************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={u'host': u'localhost', u'password': u'Password1!', u'user': u'root'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={u'host': u'localhost', u'password': u'Password1!', u'user': u'root'})

TASK [Wait for creation to finish] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for creation to finish (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for creation to finish (9 retries left).
failed: [localhost] (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'591787538842.77844', 'item': {u'host': u'localhost', u'password': u'Password1!', u'user': u'root'}, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/591787538842.77844'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "591787538842.77844", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 3, "changed": true, "cmd": "sleep 30s\n\"mysql -h localhost -u root -pPassword1! < RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log\"\n", "delta": "0:00:30.073191", "end": "2019-11-28 17:01:57.632285", "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "591787538842.77844", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": {"host": "localhost", "password": "Password1!", "user": "root"}, "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/591787538842.77844", "started": 1}, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-11-28 17:01:27.559094", "stderr": "/bin/sh: line 1: mysql -h localhost -u root -pPassword1! < RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: line 1: mysql -h localhost -u root -pPassword1! < RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
failed: [localhost] (item={'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'ansible_job_id': u'999397686792.77873', 'item': {u'host': u'localhost', u'password': u'Password1!', u'user': u'root'}, u'started': 1, 'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'finished': 0, u'results_file': u'/root/.ansible_async/999397686792.77873'}) => {"ansible_job_id": "999397686792.77873", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": true, "cmd": "sleep 30s\n\"mysql -h localhost -u root -pPassword1! < RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log\"\n", "delta": "0:00:30.120136", "end": "2019-11-28 17:01:58.694713", "finished": 1, "item": {"ansible_job_id": "999397686792.77873", "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "failed": false, "finished": 0, "item": {"host": "localhost", "password": "Password1!", "user": "root"}, "results_file": "/root/.ansible_async/999397686792.77873", "started": 1}, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-11-28 17:01:28.574577", "stderr": "/bin/sh: line 1: mysql -h localhost -u root -pPassword1! < RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: line 1: mysql -h localhost -u root -pPassword1! < RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Could you please check if  user executing playbook has permission to create log file. it seems playbook is searching log file which is missing.   ```RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: line 1: mysql -h localhost -u root -pPassword1! < RDS_script.sql >> /usr/local/testscript.log: No such file or directory"]````

Comment: Hi Ravi, I did check this initially. The log file is created. out of 2 parts of the task, 1st one where it runs the shell commands in parallel is executed successfully.
Its the 2nd part where it validates if ansible jobs are completed or not is failing.

Comment: Could you share output of playbook excution using debug mode. ( Just put "-vvv" at the end of playbook execution command and execute)

Comment: Now its working. I had a small mistake in shell section. I needed to remove the "" out of the shell script line executing sql file

Comment: Nice to hear that

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had a silly mistake which was creating trouble. I needed to remove "" from the line executing the sql file. Reproducing the correct yaml file below

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    script_file: "{{ path }}"
  vars_files:
    - dbdata.yml
  tasks:
  - name: sample command- ansible-playbook my_sqldeploy.yml --extra-vars "path=/home/NICEONDEMAND/bsahu/RDS_create_user1.sql"
    shell: |
      sleep 30s
      mysql -h {{ item.host }} -u {{ item.user }} -p{{ item.password }} < {{ script_file }} >> /usr/local/testscript.log
    with_items: "{{ conn_details }}"
    register: sql_query_output
    async: 600
    poll: 0

  - name: Wait for creation to finish
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: _jobs
    until: _jobs.finished
    delay: 20  # Check every 5 seconds. Adjust as you like.
    retries: 10
    with_items: "{{ sql_query_output.results }}"
```

Thanks all for the help.